# How to create a mobile version of an ASP.NET web site?

Tags: asp.net, mobile-website

I have a website created using asp and I want to make it accessible to mobile phones, such that a user can use it through his/her cell phone.

I don't have any knowledge of XML or .NET.

How can I do this?

Comment: I wonder how did you create an ASP.NET site without knowledge of .NET?

Comment: Is there any reason you want to develop on ASP.NET? It may help people help you by stating your programming background.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[ASP.NET Mobile Web Pages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-3.0/b73x06dt%28v=vs.85%29) says

> "The Microsoft Visual Studio integrated
> development environment (IDE) enables
> you to easily build ASP.NET
> applications that include mobile Web
> pages. You can include mobile Web
> pages in any ASP.NET Web site
> alongside ASP.NET Web pages. In Visual
> Studio, you can work with the adaptive
> rendering, customization, and
> extensibility features of ASP.NET
> mobile controls, using the standard
> IDE design tools: the page designer,
> the Toolbox, the debugger, Source
> view, Design view, and more."

[Getting Started with ASP.NET Mobile Pages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-3.0/1zh1s348%28v=vs.85%29)

---

**Some other useful tutorials:**

- [Mobile Web Development with ASP.NET 2.0](https://web.archive.org/web/20150701063344/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/trobbins/archive/2007/07/13/mobile-web-development-with-asp-net-2-0.aspx)
- [Building Mobile Web Applications with .NET Mobile Web SDK & ASP.NET](https://web.archive.org/web/20160601063739/http://www.wirelessdevnet.com:80/channels/wap/features/mobilesdk3.html)
- [Introduction to ASP.NET Mobile](https://web.archive.org/web/20160828181108/http://www.geekpedia.com:80/tutorial120_Introduction-to-ASP.NET-Mobile.html)

Answer (score 4):

Back in the day you would have needed XML to create WAP sites, but no more.  Almost all smartphones have reasonably good built in HTML browsers, with standards compliant support for JavaScript and CSS.

I would suggest making a start here:
http://www.asp.net/mobile/

Comment: hi, i don't have knowledge of .NET...
so I can not get useful information from that link...
any other help ...

Comment: @Muhammad Sajid, if you don't have knowledge on .NET I would recommend you start gaining such knowledge before trying to develop web sites on this platform. I don't see how we can help you in this situation.