# IIS/ASP/ASP.net: How to structure web-site to expose mobile version

Tags: asp.net, iis, mobile, mobile-website

Pretend i have an existing web-site, e.g.:

> www.stackoverflow.com

i now want to expose a mobile version of this web-site:

> m.stackoverflow.com

IIS, with its host-header name resolution, would normally require *two* web-sites to be created:

- www.stackoverflow.com
- m.stackoverflow.com

Except now i have two web-sites in IIS. This means i have to duplicate code/files between them. i don't need to (nor do i want to) duplicate all the "model" and "controller" code between two web-sites. i would much rather have one web-site that exposes a mobile version.

i *could* have the `default` page in `m.stackoverflow.com` simply perform a redirect to a mobile landing page on the "real" web-site:

`m.stackoverflow.com\default.asp`:

```
 <% Response.Redirect "www.stackoverflow.com/mobile" %>
```

Then the client will end up at (for example) `www.stackoverflow.com/mobile/default.aspx`.

This isn't what i want. i *want* it to appear to the browser that they are visiting `m.stackoverflow.com`.

So what i *could* do in IIS is have two host-header names for *one* IIS web-site:

- stackoverflow.com
- m.stackoverflow.com

and inspect the http-request `HOST` header:

```
GET https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ViewQuestion.aspx?qid=3623844
Host: stackoverflow.com
```

verses

```
GET https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ViewQuestion.aspx?qid=3623844
Host: m.stackoverflow.com
```

Except now my all my web-site pages must first inspect `Host` attribute, and then change rendering behavior depending on which it finds. This works somewhat well in classic ASP:

```
ViewQuestion.asp

<% Dim mobileVersion 

    ...

If MobileVersion Then
%>
<html>
...
</html>
<% Else %>
<html>
...
</html>
<% End If %>
```

But making dual view's in one page is very painful. i would *prefer* to have a `ViewQuestion` view, that is dedicated to showing a regular or mobile view.

---

i also know that i can't use the `media=handheld` media type.

- not only do i not *want* to have "full" page content being sent to mobile clients (wasting their bandwidth and download speed) and then hide content based on CSS
- not all handhelds (e.g. iPhone) honor the `media=handheld` media type

---

So what is the **accepted** combination of source-code and IIS configuration that best supports mobile versions of a web-site?

**Edit One:** Removed title reference to MVC. Don't want people to assume the use of some particular MVC framework, since i'm **not** using any MVC framework. i'm using ASP/ASP.net.

### See also

- [Redirect mobile devices to alternate version of my site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1118581/redirect-mobile-devices-to-alternate-version-of-my-site)
- [How to create mobile version of asp.NET web site?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3623844/how-to-create-mobile-version-of-asp-net-web-site)
- [Creating a mobile version of a website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1998916/creating-a-mobile-version-of-a-website)
- [What's the most efficient way to hide content for a mobile version of a site?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3185833/whats-the-most-efficient-way-to-hide-content-for-a-mobile-version-of-a-site)
- [A Better ASP.NET MVC Mobile Device Capabilities ViewEngine](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ABetterASPNETMVCMobileDeviceCapabilitiesViewEngine.aspx)

Comment: Use responsive layout, its easy and better way. There is about here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6844020/way-to-do-content-adaptation-to-mobile

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In mvc you can just submit mobile views by overriding the view engine.  We created an iphone version of our site in about 3 days.

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ABetterASPNETMVCMobileDeviceCapabilitiesViewEngine.aspx

Comment: Looked interesting, but how do you change the view?

Comment: You create a second view and the virtual path provider figures out which one to serve based on the request.

Answer (score 1):

You can use virtual directories in IIS to point both applications to the same folders so you only have one copy of your application. This is even easier if your model & controller code is in a separate from your code to produce the view.

Comment: What might that look like? Do i create a virtual directory for all folders?

Comment: You can leave your main app as is, and create your second application m.my-site.com and create virtual directories for each folder and point them to the folders in your main app. You can actually point the root at the same root as your main app as well. One thing to be aware of, if you change your web.config it will be updated for both apps. Instructions to create virtual folders are here C:\svn\branches\ezprints.com_2010-04-22\EZP\Source\EZP.Printstore.Presentation.Web

Answer (score 1):

You should check out this tool available through the MS [Web Platform Installer](http://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx)

URL Rewrite 2.0

Application Request Routing 2.5

Comment: Can you expand on how URL Rewrite 2.0 can be used to solve my problem?